# How to get only the sections containing an exact element with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to do some text processing, but cannot figure it out, the problem is:

I have a file looks like this:

```
ORANGE{  
a
b
c 
CI 123  
d
e
f
g
} 

APPLE{  
1
2
3
4
5  
CI 123  
6
7  
}  

ORANGE{  
A
B
C  
CI 321  
D
E  
} 
ORANGE{
hell
CI 123
ABCD 1234
hmmm
}
```

`awk '/ORANGE {/ {sho=1} ;/^CI 123$/ {sho=1} ;/^}$/ {sho=0} sho ' file`

I tried code above but it didn't give me exactly what I wanted, instead it gives me all the ORANGE SECTIONS. 
I googled extensively but didn't find any related info. Thanks.

Comment: @ritesht93 : Original sample data posted by the op contained a blank line which separated each sections. You sample data do not contain those. Please confirm this with OP indeed..

Comment: @sjsam ideally I think newlines would be optional unless OP explicitly mentions it is gauranteed to be present after every section; yes my data doesnt contain newlines between the last 2 sections but that doesnt affect the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat temp 
ORANGE{  
...  
CI 123  
...
} 

APPLE{  
...  
CI 123  
...  
}  

ORANGE{  
...  
CI 321  
...  
} 
ORANGE{
...
CI 123
ABCD 1234
...
}
$ awk '/ORANGE/ {o=1;p=0} {if(o)arr[i++]=$0} /CI 123/ {if(o){for(key in arr) print arr[key];p=1}else{p=0} delete arr;i=0;next;} /}/ {if(p)print;p=0;delete arr;i=0;o=0;} o && p' temp 
ORANGE{  
...  
CI 123  
...
} 
ORANGE{
...
CI 123
ABCD 1234
...
}
```

Here is the same `awk` logic in a script file with pretty identation:

```
/ORANGE/ {
    o=1
    p=0
}
{
    if(o)
        arr[i++]=$0
}
/CI 123/ {
    if(o)
    {
        for(key in arr)
            print arr[key]
        p=1
    }
    else
        p=0
    delete arr
    i=0
    next
}
/}/ {
    if(p)
        print
    p=0
    delete arr
    i=0
    o=0
}
o && p
```

And we can use the script file like this with `awk`:

```
$ awk -f script.awk temp
ORANGE{  
...  
CI 123  
...
} 
ORANGE{
...
CI 123
ABCD 1234
...
}
```

Edit1: custom data

```
$ cat temp 
ORANGE{  
a
b
c 
CI 123  
d
e
f
g
} 

APPLE{  
1
2
3
4
5  
CI 123  
6
7  
}  

ORANGE{  
A
B
C  
CI 321  
D
E  
} 
ORANGE{
hell
CI 123
ABCD 1234
hmmm
}

$ awk '/ORANGE/ {o=1;p=0} {if(o)arr[i++]=$0} /CI 123/ {if(o){for(key in arr) print arr[key];p=1}else{p=0} delete arr;i=0;next;} /}/ {if(p)print;p=0;delete arr;i=0;o=0;} o && p' temp 
ORANGE{  
a
b
c 
CI 123  
d
e
f
g
} 
ORANGE{
hell
CI 123
ABCD 1234
hmmm
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help.I just try your code in my scrip, but I got my first a few lines swapped and rest is good.:)

Comment: @Eason is your problem solved? If not.. Can you post your sample data which you are using?

Comment: Ok, I used your awk, and I got the output like this:`b
c     
CI 123    
ORANGE{    
a
d
e
f
g
} 
CI 123
ORANGE{
hell
ABCD 1234
hmmm
}
`  the first few lines swapped.

Comment: @Eason nope, I cant reproduce what you said. It works perfectly for me, edited the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS="" '/ORANGE/&&/CI 123/' file
ORANGE{  
...  
CI 123  
...
}
```

Setting the AWK record separator RS to the empty string makes each block a record. Then just search with AWK for the 2 strings you want.

Comment: Please check this with  the test pattern given in @ritesht93's answer.

Answer (score 0):

awk is your friend here :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="}\n*";ORS="}\n";}/ORANGE.*CI 123\n/{print}' file
```

Here, you set the `}\n` to the IN/OUT record separator and search for the pattern:

```
ORANGE(anything)CI 123(newline)
```

in each record, if found, print the record.

Comment: yours won't work if there are multiple `ORANGE { .. CI 123 .. }`, see my temp file's data below. It won't work for that

Comment: @ritesht93 : Rectified that issue.

Comment: Your new code eat ups the 1st `ORANGE { .. }` in my data. It only outputs `ORANGE{
...
CI 123
ABCD 1234
...
}`